# Worklight application builder never finish execution in OS X

Tags: eclipse, macos, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I have created a test application (hello world and a button) using Eclipse and Worklight 6.2.

I have 3 environments: iphone, ipad and android.
My project also includes jQuery Mobile 1.4.4.
Everything is set up correctly (ADT, Xcode, Worklight).

When I right-click myApp -> Run As > Run on Worklight Development Server, I see on the right bottom of Eclipse "Worklight application builder running". The problem is that it never finishes...

What could be the cause? Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to try:

- Close Eclipse and kill the Java process via Applications > Activity Monitor
- Close Eclipse and delete the your-workspace\worklightServerConfig folder

Then open Eclipse and try again to build the app.

Comment: I have the same issue on Windows, tried both solutions but none worked. Restarting the system doesn't help and if I close eclipse and delete the worklightServerConfig, the next time I "Run on Worklight Development Server" the project, the issue keeps appearing.

Comment: I changed the proxy configuration under Preferences>General>Network  Connections from Native to Direct and it started working again.

Comment: Impressive. Consider writing that as an answer.